# How to create seperate CSV for nested Json array in Az Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a json as below. I can flatten this in ADF using DataFlow but subject details array can hold lot of values, for which I would like to create seperate CSV.

```
{
  "studentid": 99999,
  "schoolid": "100574521",
  "name": "BLUE LAY",
  "set_id": 53,
  "subject_details": [
    {
      "subject_code": "url_key",
      "value": "100574521"
    },
    {
      "subject_code": "band",
      "value": "29732"
    },
    {
      "subject_code": "description",
      "value": "Summer "
    },
    {
      "subject_code": "options_container",
      "value": "container2"
    },
    {
      "subject_code": "has_options",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "subject_code": "category_ids",
      "value": [
        "463",
        "630"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate CSV file from the JSON nested array using the **select** in Data flows.

After creating the source for the JSON in Data flow create a **select to the source** from the options. After that, in the select settings you will see all the JSON columns and to get the nested array of JSON in the csv **delete all columns apart from `subject_details` by clicking on the delete icon** on every column.

[image]

Now, add a **sink to select** to save this in a csv file of blob.

Create respective linked service and dataset for the csv and add it to the sink.

Then, in the settings of sink and select **output to single file** from the drop down of File name option and give the **csv file name** in the Output to single file.

[image]

Execute this dataflow by the pipeline and you can see the CSV in blob.

[image]

You will get this kind of data in the csv if you do it before the flatten. So, the best practice is to **create the csv file for the nested json array after flattening it.**

Please refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) to know more about the Flatten in Data flow.

After flattening the JSON, you can use the **same select option to create the csv** from it by deleting all columns apart from these two like above. If you want, you can **export the data as csv** in the `Data preview of select` itself.

[image]

Then add sink and execute the data flow and you can see the csv data like below in the blob.

[image]

In your JSON nested array, the `value` had different data types like **string in first 5 rows** and **array in the last one**. It will be difficult to flatten that, so try to maintain the **same data type for the `value` like `array` for all rows** if you face any issues in flatten.